# Mobile App for Website Integration

Tags: android, mobile

If I have a responsive website instead of a mobile app and I still want the ability to do things like notifications from the website, is there an existing mobile app (a sort of message broker perhaps) that will allow my website to make calls to the app which will then create the notifications, etc on my website's behalf without me actually having to create my own mobile app?

Comment: I think there is no such kind of app exists for now but not sure.

Comment: Quick thought: Might that be a case for an [IFTTT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFTTT) recipe? That would make it available for iOS as well then :)